# how to reduce size of text code in C language?

Tags: c

I am trying to reduce the size of text in C (gcc )

when I typed size command, the text size was 4096.
[image]

the program is simple

[image]

and then, when I erased newline and initialization like this,

[image]

the result is same with before.

I mean the text size is still 4096

[image]

how to reduce the size of text??

Comment: Removing whitespaces from your source code won't reduce the size of your executable

Comment: learn how to program first. and it is not possible.

Comment: So,what do you think is taking the space---remove all the indentations,it'll show you the same size.

Comment: 1+ for using the "*Green Screen*" ... ;-)

Comment: [ŮPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Use a smaller font. (Which is as logical as removing the whitespace in your source.)

Answer (score 2):

`__TEXT` segment is where your actual compiled code resides, not related directly to the size of the source code file.

- The most significant means of controlling code size belongs to design - design your program correctly, avoid redundant logic.
- Microoptimizations like combining variable definition and initialization are meaningless, compiler will do it better than you anyway.
- Compiler has different optimization options, normally variating between speed improvement to code size improvement. Set the optimization level for minimal code size.

Answer (score 0):

The `__TEXT` denotes the [Text/Code Segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) of the program. It contains the executable instructions of the program. And `4096` is the size of that segment and not the size of the text in your source file.

Comment: For PE executable, the segment size is aligned to the page size which is 4K.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the change won't reduce the size of your exe file is that, in the compilation process, is the preprocessor will handle the whitespaces. If you want to know more about it, you should study the compilation process.